# how to add image slider to a wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

how to add image slider to word press theme home page which doesn't have an inbuilt support means which code to add and how. I have no idea about adding a slider to a word press home page which doesn't have a slider already.

I want free plugin as i dont have enough funds to buy a new plugin..

Answer (score 1):

Just add the Rev Slider plugin and use its code, which will be something like [slider_id123] and paste wherever you want to use that slider.

Answer (score 0):

you can develop your slider via the rev slider plugin and then it gives you a piece of php code to paste in your template page. Is everything clear?

Answer (score 0):

there are many slider plugins you can use but the best ones are in the links i pasted and you can choose it according to your need

http://www.wpbeginner.com/best-wordpress-slider/